# How to add days into my date using angular pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I'm trying to add certain amount of days at my date, using pipe.

So I created the pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import * as moment from 'moment/moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'DataEncerramento'
})
export class DataEncerramentoPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(dataAgendamento: any, prazo: any ): any {
    if (dataAgendamento) {
      return moment(dataAgendamento).add(prazo, 'days');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And tried it on my template

```
<p-column header="Data de encerramento" [style]="{ width: '200px' }">
      <ng-template let-solicitacao="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <p *ngIf="solicitacao.dataAgendamento; else naoAgendada">
            {{ solicitacao.DataEncerramento | DataEncerramentoPipe: 'solicitacao.dataAgendamento': 'solicitacao.prazo' }}
        </p>
        <ng-template #naoAgendada>
          <p>Não agendada</p>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

But I have the follow error:

```
The pipe 'DataEncerramentoPipe' could not be found
```

even if I had this pipe imported at my module.

Comment: the name of your pipe is `DataEncerramento` not `DataEncerramentoPipe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your pipe definition:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'DataEncerramento'
})
```

use the same name in HTML:

`DataEncerramento` **not** `DataEncerramentoPipe`